# &#65279; causing padding?

Tags: php, wordpress, encoding, utf-8, spacing

I edited a PHP file with dreamweaver and all of a sudden i got a white spacing on the top. When i used inspect element in my browser I found this code `&#65279;`, causing the break. When i open my PHP file with notepad++ I see the file is encoded to UTF8. When i change it to ansi or utf-8 without BOM, the problem disappears. Now my questions is; why does this problem occur, how can i fix the problem from within Dreamweaver, and does encoding the file to ansi or utf-8 without BOM (or anything else) harm the file itself?

Thanks

Comment: you got a whitespace to the top? without boom? wtf are you trying to say?

Comment: By "boom", I think he/she means [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: "how can i fix the problem from within Dreamweaver" by saving without BOM. And no it does not harm the file as long as you keep utf8. Just without BOM.

Comment: Utf without BOM of course :)